# Help me blow up a space station

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'd like to create a scenario where there is space station debris scattered in an area within a `0.5km` radius for at least an in-game hour or so. The space station is has one center structural part, and this is the part I'd like to blow up. How can I make it explode?

Comment: Anything you do to make it disintigrate will spread the debris further and further as time goes on. There's no way to contain it within a half kilometer.

Comment: @Frank, I know that, I'd just like it to be within the `0.5km` radius for period of time.

Comment: What part is the structural part? (fuel tank, girder, etc.)

Comment: And how do you feel about mods? If you're willing to use one mod, I can give you a very easy way to do this

Comment: @SaintWacko The part is an empty Mobile Processing Lab, and yes, I'm willing to use mods if it requires it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you would like to do it without mods, you can use the Whack A Kerbal in the debug menu.  Open the Debug Menu by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.  Then select the "Show Whack A Kerbal" option.  Fire the object by pressing the Middle Mouse Button.  I would recommend quicksaving before doing this, in case you miss the intended target.

Comment: You may or may not mean Alt+F12.

Comment: I fixed that, it was a typo, haha.

Comment: Oh. This is the best option. I was going to suggest using the explosives from KIS to blow up the core, but this is a much better idea. I completely forgot about Whack-A-Kerbal. I'd recommend, when you use it, to set the speed and mass to maximum, and size to minimum. This makes it easier to target a single part.

Comment: @SaintWacko I looked at that option too, but since I've never used it before, I decided to stay away from it.

Comment: In case there are readers who are not aware of every single mod ever made: What @SaintWacko meant with "KIS" is the mod "[Kerbal Inventory System](http://www.curse.com/ksp-mods/kerbal/228561-kerbal-inventory-system-kis)"